# Display image as property of a ChoiceField in a form

Tags: django, django-forms

Hi Have a choice field

```
   class PropertyReportForm(forms.Form):    
    property = forms.ChoiceField(widget = forms.RadioSelect,required = False)
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        properties = kwargs.pop('properties')               
        property_choice = []
        for property1 in properties:                        
            index = (property1.id,"Name :"+property1.name+" Area:"+str(property1.area)+" "+property1.image)
            property_choice.append(index)                
        super( PropertyReportForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['property'].choices = property_choice
```

Now while displaying I want it to display
[image: Like this]

How can I do this?
Template code similar to what I want. This does not work. But I want this

```
 {% for field in propertyreportform %}
     {{ field }}    <img src="/media/{{ field.image }}" />                                                  
  {% endfor %}
```

Comment: You want it checked when it loads? In that case you can supply the `initial={}` to the form when it renders.

Comment: No I dont want iot checked. I want to display the image associated wuth that property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem you basically have three options:

1. Create your own renderer, and use it as argument for `ChoiceField`, unfortunately you will need to create it from scratch, since django doesn't allow you to simply override `RadioFieldRenderer` class. https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5.4/django/forms/widgets.py#L693
2. Just loop over your choices and use manually created radio input tags, there's not a lot of validation to do and retrieving selected item or model object is also simple enough.
3. The simplest and less recommended way could be to include the whole image tag inside label string (use settings to get media url part).